# Git Bash slow PageDown

Tags: git-bash

I'm using Git Bash on Windows 10. I've selected [Use Windows' default console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8nY2.png).

When I scroll with PageUp/PageDown, it's slow, not like in Linux. In Linux, it's instantaneous, while here it is animated - I can see how it goes down line one 30 times, instead of just going 30 lines down. It's like PageDown gets interpreted as me hitting DownArrow 20-30 times.

Has anyone experienced the same problem, and do you know of any workarounds?

Comment: So cat /c/Program\ Files/Git/etc/install-options.txt shows you a "Bash Terminal Option" set to ConHost? (as in https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/800#issuecomment-270020774) If so, that seems expected (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1395)

Comment: Just in case, as in https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/800#issuecomment-229029511, try `stty sane`

Comment: @VonC Yes, I get `Bash Terminal Option: ConHost`

Comment: I see in your screenshot 2.7.0. Did you tried it with Git 2.16.2?

Comment: @VonC The screenshot was from Google Images. Sorry, it was a bit misleading. My version is  2.15.0.windows.1.

Comment: Does the issue persists with 2.16.2?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce that with a Windows 10 and Git 2.16.2: the scrolling is instantaneous, be it in a `CMD` after typing '`bash`', or in a git bash window, after typing '`git bash`'.

Try again, with Git referenced by a simplified PATH (set in a dedicated CMD session, just for testing):

```
set G=c:\path\to\latest\git
set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Check that, in your bash session, `TERM` is set to `xterm`.

You can also test that bash session with:

```
export LESS=-JMQRSiFX
```

In any case, a `less longFile` should propose the long file content immediately, and "page Up/Down" should work without delay.